# Implementing services layer with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing persistence layer for my ASP.NET Core application using Entity Framework Core. I [read](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/) that using Repository pattern is unnecessary, because it's already implemented by `DBSet`. But what about Services layer (if that's what it's called)?

Using Repository pattern I pass, for example `UserRepository`, to `UserServices` constructor. Also, I expose Get/Add/Update.. methods, so my Controllers receive only services through Dependency Injection. But if I do the same with `DBSet` methods like this:

```
public void AddUser(User user)
{
   this.context.Users.Add(user);
}
```

... then I will wrap the already implemented `DbSet.Add()` method logic, which I tried to avoid by not implementing the Repository pattern.

So my question is what are the best practices for implementing services for working with Entity Framework? I found only discussions about necessity of Repository pattern implementation, but not the services. Should I pass context to controllers and create services by extension methods for specific `DBSet`? Or should I pass both services and context to controller, so my services will not wrap already implemented methods in `DBSet` and only cover other specific methods (like get grouped Companies and their Employees)? Or wrapping `DBSet` methods is valid for service layer?

Comment: Your server is a two port application.  One port is the connection to the client using the controller.  The second port is a connection to the database.  The controller uses a class object to pass data between the client and server.  Then you will take the class object and send the data to the database.  There is no reason that you cannot make a property in the controller class object a DBSet.